# Weird bottom area from fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

Now i try to make my site by fullpage.js plugin.

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks

But there is a weird bottom area inside the section that have content which longer than their section height. (Section that have scrollOverflow)

Like this.

[image]

This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        'navigation': true,
        paddingTop: '0',
        paddingBottom: '0',
        scrollOverflow: true,
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            //using anchorLink
            if(anchorLink == 'grey-fade-bg-slide'){
                //alert("eoaehou");
                $("body").css("background-image","url('img/team-bg.jpg')");
            }

            if(anchorLink == 'banner-slide'){
                //$("#map").css("height","120px");
                if(window.location.href.indexOf("our-team-bg-slide") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("contact-us-bg-slide") > -1 ) {
                    //alert("ccccc");
                    $("body").css("background-image","url('img/team-bg.jpg')");
                }
            }

            if(anchorLink == 'blue-bg-slide'){
                //alert("eoaehou");
                $("body").css("background-image","url('img/banner-bg-image.jpg')");
            }
        },
        afterRender: function(){
            initMap();
            $(".our-team-bg-section h3").css("margin-top","120px");
            $(".contact-us-bg-section h3").css("margin-top","60px");
            $(".grey-fade-bg-section h3").css("margin-top","120px");
        }

    });
});
```

All js file that i included.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scrolloverflow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easings.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me that the map above was not fitting in a single screen so it got split onto a new slide.

Comment: Yeah the content is larger that a single screen, so i turn on scrollOverflow for them can scroll in just one screen but it still longer than it should be.

Comment: Are you including the external scrolloverflow.js library as indicated in the documentation? You are not sharing enough with us so we here's really no way of helping, just guessing.

Comment: yes, i edited the code.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the class `fp-auto-height` as detailed [in the fullpage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections).

See the [demo online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html) or the one [in codepen](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/BKjRYm).

```
<div class="section">Whole viewport</div>
<div class="section fp-auto-height">Auto height</div>
```

Comment: i am not sure why but when i stop using their .css and then use their .scss instead every thing is solved.